# How to enable v-pre only for child elements and text nodes?

Tags: vue.js

I have an HTML server-side template that looks like this:

```
<div id="vue">
  <button v-pre>{% trans "Save" %}</button>
</div>
```

The server-side templating language will replace `{% trans "Save" %}` with the translated string, with `<`, `>` and `&` escaped to `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;` respectively. However, it won't escape the Vue delimiters. For this reason, to be safe, I've used [`v-pre`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-pre) directive in the element, as is recommended when mixing server-side templating with Vue. Here is the documentation for `v-pre`:

> `v-pre`: Skip compilation for this element and all its children.

Some time later, I modify the code to include a `v-if` condition, like this:

```
<div id="vue">
  <button v-if="condition" v-pre>{% trans "Save" %}</button>
</div>
```

It doesn't work. The problem is that the `v-if` directive has no effect, because of the `v-pre` directive.

What I'm looking for is something like the `v-pre` directive that will turn off compilation for all the element's children (including child text nodes), but won't turn off other directives on the same element. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to use a child `<template>` element, like this:

```
<div id="vue">
  <button v-if="condition">
    <template v-pre>{% trans "Save" %}</template>
  </button>
</div>
```